# java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java.nio.file

I´ve got this exception provider not found, but don´t know how to solve it. Here is my code:

```
 @Bean
    public FileSystem fileSystem() {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/home/Desktop/mydir");
            FileSystem ext2fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            
            return ext2fs;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to solve it.
The idea is that i have this bean for filesystem, which i will later use for crud operation, but this bean is because if i later want to change storage that it would be easily just changed in this bean, for example if i want to use google as storage instead of local storage or something like that just set it up in this method. I´m using Spring Boot 2.3.3

**Update - complete exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystem' defined in class path resource [Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.nio.file.FileSystem]: Factory method 'fileSystem' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.nio.file.FileSystem]: Factory method 'fileSystem' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:407) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at Config.fileSystem(FileSystemConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0.CGLIB$fileSystem$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ee51dad.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0.fileSystem(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

**New update**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkUri(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:69) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:221) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at FileSystemConfig.fileSystem(FileSystemConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at FileSystemConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0.CGLIB$fileSystem$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at FileSystemConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ee51dad.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at FileSystemConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53bc71a0.fileSystem(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the complete exception message with its stack trace.

Comment: @Milgo added the complete exception message

Answer (score 4):

You chose the `newFileSystem()` method with a class object as second parameter. This second parameter must be a class of an file systems provider which is not in this case. Please just use something like:

```
@Bean
public FileSystem fileSystem() {
    Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("file:/C:/Users/home/Desktop/mydir"));
    final URI uri = URI.create("file:" + path.toUri().getPath());
    FileSystem ext2fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);

    return ext2fs;
}
```

Comment: try this: Path path = Paths.get("c:\\data\\myfile.txt")  if you are using windows.                                                                     The double \ characters are necessary in Java strings, since the \ is an escape character, meaning the following character tells what character is really to be located at this place in the string. By writing \\ you tell the Java compiler to write a single \ character into the string.

Comment: yes, I´m using windows and put the path with double \ but got same exception

Comment: `Paths.get(URI.create("file:/C:/Users/home/Desktop/mydir"));` should work

Comment: again same exception